# "Cannot change contribution status from Overdue to Completed" (4.4.20)

Tags: civicontribute

We have a number of membership-related contributions that are in Overdue status, as they were promised but not paid on time. Now they have been paid, so in reality they are completed and no longer overdue.

When we attempt to edit the contribution we get the error message in the title. I understand that status transitions are restricted to preserve the integrity of financial transactions- but finally receiving an overdue payment sounds like a sensible transition (and we aren't using Civi for our actual accounts anyway, our finance officer uses a separate accounts package). Is there a correct way of doing this for end users, ie without manually changing it in the database? (We're using 4.4.20)

Comment: Are these contributions based on pledges? If thats the case should you be amending via pledge?

Comment: Hi Parvez, no we don't use pledges at all. These are contributions that are payments for memberships. I don't know how they actually got to be overdue- I see it isn't an option when editing existing contributions manually, and isn't even an option when searching with "Find Contributions".

Comment: Must be a status thats been setup at FF and it must be a terminal status? Can you check your contribution statuses and see what the settings are?

Comment: Aha, I've found somewhere they can become overdue. It's when you're adding a membership and its contribution together ("Record Membership Payment?" ticked). "Overdue" is an option in "Payment Status".